# Leading divergent term in integral before integration

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, gamma-function, laurent-series, beta-function

Consider, for example, the Beta function:

$$ B(\alpha,1+\alpha) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+2\alpha)} = \int_0^1 dt\ t^\alpha (1-t)^{\alpha-1}. $$

Expanding the integrated result in small $\alpha$, there is a leading term $1/\alpha$ that is divergent. However, if one tries to expand the integrand and then perform the integral, this term is "lost" and instead the leading contribution is a divergent integral:

$$ \int_0^1 dt\ \frac{1}{1-t}.$$

Now, is there a smart way to recover the leading $1/\alpha$ term by expanding before integration?

Comment: $$\int_0^1 t^\alpha (1-t)^{\alpha-1}dt=\int_0^1 (t^\alpha-1) (1-t)^{\alpha-1}dt+\int_0^1(1-t)^{\alpha-1}dt$$
$$\overset{\text{at}\,\alpha\to 0}{\to}\alpha\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt+O(\alpha^2)+\frac1\alpha=\frac1\alpha-\frac{\pi^2}6\alpha+O(\alpha^2)$$